# Trivial function gives unexpected return value

Tags: c++, boolean, double

I have coded a function which receives a double matrix and looks backwards for a zero entry. If it finds one it changes the value of that entry to `-2.0` and returns `true`. Otherwise it returns `false`.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool remove1zero(std::vector<std::vector<double>> & matrix)
{
    size_t dim = matrix.size();
    for (size_t j = dim - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        for (size_t i = dim - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if ((matrix[j])[i] == 0.0)
            {
                (matrix[j])[i] = -2.0;
                return true;
            }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> testMatrix(3);
    testMatrix[0] = std::vector<double> {-2.0, -2.0, 3.0};
    testMatrix[1] = std::vector<double> {-2.0, -1.0, 3.0};
    testMatrix[2] = std::vector<double> {2.0, 2.0, -1.0};
    std::cout << remove1zero(testMatrix);
}
```

Since that matrix has no zero entry, the if-condition shouldn't activate, and eventually `remove1zero` should return `false`. However, that's not what happens. I have tried it on my machine as well as in http://cpp.sh/ and the output is `1`/`true`. I would appreciate any insight on why this happens.

Comment: With (unsigned) `size_t j = dim - 1;`, `j >= 0` is always true. so you have out of bound access, instead of stopping the loop.

Comment: [OT]: No need of parenthesis in `(matrix[j])[i]`, `matrix[j][i]` is enough.

Comment: @Jarod42 Now it all makes sense! It is weird though that nothing complains when attempting to decrement a `size_t` variable with current value `0`. Thank you!!

Comment: Also, research what fuzzy-compare means, and use it whenever comparing `double` or `float`.

Comment: @edgystyle `unsigned` integer types are defined to work using modulo arithmetic, so decrementing from 0 is required to wrap around to the maximum value. Since this is reliable, a developer can use that meaningfully so it isn't necessarily an error. It would be impractical to complain when something allowed is done. With `signed` integer types though, overflow and underflow are Undefined Behavior and a compiler *may* issue a warning, or it *may* crash or complain at runtime.

Comment: I though that `j >= 0` would produce a warning about "always true", but seems not :(.

Comment: @Jarod42 gcc does warn about that, but you need `-Wextra` or `-Wtype-limits` : https://godbolt.org/z/ThMnGvPrE

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Tested (unsuccessfully) `-Wextra` with clang, but not gcc :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, as `size_t` is an *unsigned* type, the `j >= 0` and `i >= 0` comparisons will *always* evaluate as "true" and, when either index reaches zero, the next value (after decrementing that zero value) will wrap around to the maximum value for the `size_t` type, causing undefined behaviour (out-of-bounds access).

A nice 'trick' to get round this is to use the "goes to" pseudo-operator, `-->`, which is actually a combination of two operators: [What is the "-->" operator in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/10871073).

You can use this in your `for` loops as outlined below, leaving the "iteration expression" blank (as the decrement is done in the "condition expression") and starting the loop at a one higher index in the "init-statement" (as that decrement will be applied *before* entering the body of the loop).

Here's a version of your function using this approach (note that I have included a space in the `x-- > 0` expressions, to clarify that there are actually two separate operators involved):

```cpp
bool remove1zero(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix)
{
    size_t dim = matrix.size();
    for (size_t j = dim ; j-- > 0; )
        for (size_t i = dim ; i-- > 0; )
            if (matrix[j][i] == 0.0) {
                matrix[j][i] = -2.0;
                return true;
            }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`size_t` is equal to `unsigned long`. When you check `j` or `i` in the for loop, you can't get a negative number. Therefore `j` and `i` get a weird value when you subtract 1 from 0. The solution is to change `size_t` to a simple `long`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool remove1zero(std::vector<std::vector<double>> & matrix)
{
    long dim = (long)matrix.size();
    for (long j = dim - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        for (long i = dim - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (matrix[j][i] == 0.0)
            {
                matrix[j][i] = -2.0;
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> testMatrix(3);
    testMatrix[0] = std::vector<double> {-2.0, -2.0, 3.0};
    testMatrix[1] = std::vector<double> {-2.0, -1.0, 3.0};
    testMatrix[2] = std::vector<double> {2.0, 2.0, -1.0};
    std::cout << remove1zero(testMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use size_t as type for the loops. It can evaluate less than zero because it is unsigned.  Just cast the size to an integer and work with that.

```
bool remove1zero(std::vector<std::vector<double>> & matrix)
{
    int dim = (int)matrix.size();
    printf("matrix size=%d\n",dim);
    for (int j = dim - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        for (int i = dim - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            printf("%d, %d\n",i,j);
            if ((matrix[j])[i] == 0.0)
            {
                (matrix[j])[i] = -2.0;
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With (unsigned) `size_t j = dim - 1;`, `j >= 0` is always `true`. so you have out of bound access, instead of stopping the loop.

In C++20, with [`std::ranges::reverse_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view)

you might do:

```
bool remove1zero(std::vector<std::vector<double>> & matrix)
{
    for (auto& col : matrix | std::views::reverse)) {
        for (double& d : col | std::views::reverse) {
            if (d == 0.0) {
                d = -2.0;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jEncv71Er)